# Submitting two forms with a single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to submit two forms with a single submit button. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You can't combine the two forms into one?

Comment: @Austin: The forms may be targeting different URLs.

Comment: @Ates Maybe, but the reason wasn't specified, and it never hurts to consider the easy answer first.  :]

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
   $('#form2').submit();
});
```

However, this probably will only submit one of them (unless they are submitted with XHR).

You can loop through the other form's input elements and append them to your other form on submit.

Comment: +1 for the appending other form to the first. Probably the best way to go about it. Just name the elements intelligently (`form1-input1`, `form1-input2`, .. `form2-input1`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with combine data from Form1 and Form2.

HTML Code:

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="example.php">
   <input type="text" value="Testing" name="var1">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form method="post" id="myForm2" action="example2.php">
  <input type="text" value="Testing2" name="var2">      
</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('#myForm').submit( function(){    
    url= $('#myForm').attr("action");
    data= $('#myForm').serialize();
    data2= $('#myForm2').serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data + '&' + data2, // Combine data from myForm and myForm2 using & character
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```