# PHP get request with multiple parameters from different forms

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I'm new to PHP and have a little problem. I'm trying to set up a get Request with two parameters. The URL should for example look like this:

```
search.php?query=Harry+Potter&page=movies
```

The problem is, that i get the two parameters 'query' and 'page' from two different forms.

My Code is the following:

Form 1:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default c-nav-btn-height" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
<form class="btn-group-vertical" action="search.php" method="get">
  <button id="bMovies" class="btn active-menu" type="submit" name="page" value="movies">Filme</button>
  <button id="bSeries" class="btn" type="submit" name="page" value="series">Serien</button>
</form>
```

Are there any possibilities to combine two forms in one get Request?

Comment: Maybe use sessions or cookies for the first request, you can only do one request per request.

Comment: Why have two forms if you want them to be submitted at the same time with data from both?

Comment: Why use different forms?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The Problem is that i have a search field which is the 'Form 1' in my description. This search field is on every page on my website. If I'm submitting this form, it sends the data to search.php where i can choose between two options, 'movies' and 'series'. This two options are my second form.

Comment: @C0dekid Thats not what im trying to do, both parameters have to be in the URL... Anyways, thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm guessing that only the second form should trigger the first, while the first shouldn't trigger the second? (since there are only buttons and no text field)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The second form is not accessible before submitting the first one. After you search for something (for example the movie "The A-Team") in the search field you will get to a page where the results are displayed. The Problem is, the results are separated in Movies and Series and with the second form i want to make it possible to switch between all movies or all series which refer to "The A-Team".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as able to fix the problem with some help from the comment section - thanks to [@Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson). Unfortunately he deleted some of his comments, so I will answer this questions by myself.

To clarify, I know this is for sure not the best way to do it, but Hell Yeah, it works!

**Solution:**

Hidden input fields did it for me. I added one hidden input field in each form:

*Form 1:*

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" class="navbar-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="movies">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="query">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default c-nav-btn-height" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

*Form 2:*

```
<form class="btn-group-vertical" action="search.php" method="get">
  <button id="bMovies" class="btn active-menu" type="submit" name="page" value="movies">Filme</button>
  <button id="bSeries" class="btn" type="submit" name="page" value="series">Serien</button>
  <input id="hiddenField" type="hidden" name="query" value="">
</form>
```

So I added a hidden input field named "page" in the first form and a hidden input field named "query" in the second form. With this little trick im able to get the same information in both forms, but only the fields I want to show are shown.

Since the *Form 1* is submitted first, it is possible to copy the value of the visible input field into the invisible input field in *Form 2*. All i need is some extra PHP and JavaScript.

```
$query = $_GET["query"];
$page = $_GET["page"];
if ($page == "movies" || $page == "series") {
  echo "<script>";
  echo 'document.getElementById("hiddenField").value = "'. $query .'" ;';
  echo "</script>";
}
else {
}
```

I store the two parameters from the first Form into variables and check if `$page` is 'movies' or 'series', because only these two options are allowed on this site. If it is true, it echos some JavaScript, which is adding the `$query` variable as the value of the hidden input field in the second form.

And again, i know there will be better ways to do it, but it worked for me and i wanted to share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

well, not natively, and if you can avoid it, you should. if you can combine both forms on your page, do that. if.. for some reason you really can't, i suggest you have a look at this thread.. it has a javascript function to do what you are looking to accomplish
[jQuery - submit multiple forms through single reqest, without Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057833/jquery-submit-multiple-forms-through-single-reqest-without-ajax)

Comment: You can also do the same without including a bloated JS framework, unless you're already using it for other stuff.